# how to display 2012/00/00 date wpf datagrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a date column in MySQL table which has dates like (2012/00/00).When I want to display the date in WPF DataGrid, runtime gives an error " Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime", but when date is complete like(2012/01/01) it displays the date. your help is much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Please show the exact line of code where there is an error 2) Is it a compiler error or a runtime error ? 3) What is the exact type of your SQL Column ? Regards

Comment: it is a common code : sql query="select * from mytable";

Comment: Here you show sql code. You say there is a compiler error (I think it 's a runtime error) - so show the code that reads the SQL if you want to be helped. Anyway the problem isin the SQL/C# conversion so agin , show the code. If Gustav gave the fix, reward him and mark the question as answered.

Comment: @EmmanuelDURIN yes, it's a runtime error. the problem is with sql to c# conversion, using a data adapter  i fill the data to data table and there comes the error at run time. this datatable is datagrid source

Answer (score 0):

That's because MySQL has a bad habit of allowing non-specific date entries like *a date of 2012* using 00 for month or day or both.

Thus, you'll have to decide for a default month/day for such entries and perform a replace to, say, January 1th:

```
string dateDb = "2012/00/00";
DateTime dateValid = DateTime.Parse(dateDb.Replace("/00", "/01"));

// Returns the date value: 2012-01-01
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I seached alot for a way to display 00/00 but I couldn't find a good solution

Comment: True, there is no good solution, so you'll either have to _convert_ similar to what I've shown, or _filter_ out these values and display as _N/A_, or read the data as strings and _display as is_. And do send a _Thank You!_ to Oracle/MySQL for allowing invalid dates.